# Custom URI Schema on Windows

Tags: windows

I'd like to install an application on Windows with a custom URI schema. meaning, I'd like links such as:

myApp://

to be opened by my own application to handle that resource.

Any idea how I achieve that? is there a registry area that handles this? if I do that, will it be honored by applications that launch links, like Outlook for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are kept in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` along with file associations.

There is a simple explanation in MSDN: [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

Most Windows programs honor system-wide associations.